# Inconsistency in Tables - Mariadb Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera, xtradb-cluster

MariaDB cluster Version : mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.24-MariaDB,

I have a two node + arbitrator cluster which is live and replicating data across nodes.

Unfortunately we found some inconsistency in some of the tables in Databases.

For instance:

Node1:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select count(*) from example_db.reports;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      299 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Node2:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select count(*) from example_db.reports;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      285 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: Not find any noticeable errors in mysql error log

What could be the reasons for these kind of inconsistency ?

Is that a bug or a known issues ?

Thank you.

Comment: please upload your mariadb log to GitHub Gist or other paste service. Please post details about your configuration (my.cnf). Are in datadir *.GRA files?

Answer (score 1):

`pt-table-checksum` supports Galera. Try it to see if there are any inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks @akuzminsky for the response. I confirmed that there are inconsistency in some tables. And pt-table-checksum only supports for STATEMENT. But my binlog_format is ROW.

Comment: That's not correct. pt-tc depends on STATEMENT format which it sets in its own session. So, it works perfectly fine even if binlog_format is ROW.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html#limitations

Comment: Oh, you found the documentation! Why don't you read it now ?